# ¿Se puede usar el indirecto para contestar a “qué”?

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos, preguntas

No sé si es correcto decir: “*¿Qué quieres? → a Emma*.”
¿Se puede usar la forma indirecta para contestar esta pregunta?

Comment: Si te refieres a la presposición "a" (propia del objeto indirecto) delante de "Emma", no solo se puede, sino que es necesaria. Emma es un objeto directo, pero también es una persona, por lo que requiere la preposición "a". "Quiero a Emma" es correcto; "quiero Emma" no lo es.

Comment: @Yay - gracias pero,una cosa, que es la regla de la gramática que define esta condición? Con a referencia a este detalle, sería una contesta no solo un comentario

Comment: @roberto En [esta entrada de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg) se detallan los casos en los que la preposición "a" es obligatoria para introducir un complemento directo. La primera norma es "Ante nombres propios de persona o animal". No posteo el comentario como una respuesta porque no termino de entender la pregunta. Si qdii la aclara, la postearé con más detalle.

Comment: No es lo que quiero decir, sino me gustaría saber si es correcto preguntar ¿Qué quieres? y responder el nombre de una persona en vez de formular la pregunta con el complemento indirecto ¿A quién quieres?.

Comment: Se debería preguntar ¿A quién quieres? si el que pregunta sabe que la respuesta va a ser una persona. Si no sabe cuál va a ser la respuesta, no tiene sentido preguntar "a quién" en vez de "qué". Por ejemplo, dos amigos están enamorados de una misma chica (Emma), y uno quiere algo (por ejemplo, que el otro le ayude con un examen), y el segundo le dice "Si me das algo a cambio". El primero le podría preguntar ¿Qué quieres?, a lo que el segundo le podría responder "A Emma", y tanto pregunta como respuesta serían perfectamente correctas. Por cierto, ¿a quién quieres? pregunta por un CD, no un CI.

Answer (score 2):

> -¿Qué quieres?
> -A Emma

Es incorrecto si se interpreta el verbo "querer" como "amar", mientras que en el sentido de "qué deseas" estaría bien. Por otra parte:

> -¿A quién quieres?
> -A Emma

es correcto en cualquier caso.

Lo siguiente podría parecer correcto en estructura pero no tendría ningún sentido:

> -¿Qué quieres?
> -Emma.

"A Emma", aunque parezca un complemento indirecto, es en realidad directo. Los complementos directos referidos a una persona [suelen llevar la preposición "a"](http://www.profesorenlinea.cl/castellano/CDirecto.htm)

## CONCLUSIÓN

El verbo querer es muy utilizado, por lo que tiene múltiples significados. Si lo interpretas como "amar" lleva *"a alguien"* y si lo interpretas como "desear" lleva *"a algo"* (aquí *algo* puede ser un nombre de persona, en cuyo caso iría introducido por "a"). En el caso de ser una pregunta, la primera acepción exigiría la preposición obligatoriamente (¿A quién quieres?), mientras que en su segunda acepción la preposición puede omitirse (¿Qué quieres?). Puede resultar una falta de respeto tratar a una persona como un objeto, pero podría darse si el que formula la pregunta no sabe si la respuesta va a ser una persona o un objeto. El resto de significados de "querer" tendrán cada uno su interpretación, supongo que se aprenderá a usar cada uno con la práctica (yo tuve que hacer eso mismo en francés).

Comment: *"-¿Qué quieres? -A Emma. Es incorrecto"* ¿En qué te basas para decir que es incorrecto? A mí me parece perfectamente correcto, y una pregunta y respuesta bastante naturales en el contexto adecuado.

Comment: @Yay tienes razón, estaba pensando en otro contexto (querer de amar, no de desear)

Comment: @Yay si te apetece editar algo para mejorar mi respuesta siéntete libre de hacerlo.

Comment: Igual estoy en desacuerdo, suena completamente normal "A emma" pero cada quién lo dice como quiere y yo diría Quiero a emma

Comment: @Jaime he puesto que esta bien...